# Theorem $2.15$ of Quiver Representations by Ralf Schiffler.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, notation, representation-theory, quiver

I'm reading the proof of theorem $2.15$ of Quiver Representations by Karl Schiffler. The author states the following:

Let $Q$ be a finite acyclic quiver, $M=(\left\{M_i\right\}_{i\in Q_0}, \left\{\phi_{\alpha}\right\}_{\alpha\in Q_1})$ a quiver and let $d_i=\dim M_i$. We define a projective representation $P_0:=\bigoplus_{i\in Q_{i}}d_iP(i)$, here $P(i)$ denotes the indecomposable projective representation associated to the vertex $i$. Recall that $P(i)_j$ is the vector space with basis given by all paths from $i$ to $j$.

The author then states that the set $$\left\{c_{ij}\mid i\in Q_0,  c_i \mbox{ is a path such that $s(c_i)=i$ (i.e. $c_i$ begins in $i$), j=1, \dots , d_i}\right\}$$ is a basis of $P_0$. However, I do not understand why this is so.

When I read the basis in words, I read that for each vertex $i$ we consider $d_i$ times a path $c_i$ that starts in $i$.

Now I believe this is incorrect, as $P(i)_j$ is spanned by all paths from $i$ to $j$, $P(i)$ is spanned by all paths beginning at $i$. Hence a basis of $P_0$ is given by

$$\bigcup_{i\in Q_0}\left\{\mbox{$d_i$ times all paths beginning at $i$}\right\}.$$

Am I wrong or is the author just using some (mild) abuse of notation?

Comment: The basis is pairs $(c_i,j)$ where $c_i$ runs through all paths beginning at $i$ and $j=1,\dots, d_i$. The author uses $d_iP(i)$ to denote the direct sum of $d_i$ copies of $P(i)$, maybe this is where your confusion comes from?

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer: So there should be three indices, $c_{i,n,j}$ where $n$ denotes the $n$-th path beginning at $i$, in the author's notation there is no way to distinguish between two paths starting at $i$.

Comment: No, I think the author uses shorthand $c_{ij}$ (abuse of notation) for the pair $(c_i,j)$ as I wrote above.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer: Thank you, so it is (mild) abuse of notation as I already stated above. I don't mind this since the correct notation is overloaded, but using abuse of notation without saying so might cause some confusion. I'm quite new to the subject, so I'm still somewhat wary for mistakes. But in hindsight, this notation works fine.